# What are some real-life use cases for XSLT 3.0 streaming?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Could this technology be effectively used for stock tickers, social media streams, etc? Is XSLT currently being used for either of these purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the use cases studied by the XSLT working group during the requirements phase for XSLT 3.0 (or XSLT 2.1 as it was then) are described here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-21-requirements/

They are all based on practical experience of WG members, so they are "real-life" in that sense, but of course they are abstracted to draw out the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Some use cases involving very large XML files where I used XSLT-

1. Social media streaming- Get all the social media items from various channel API like Facebook, Twitter etc. using server-side scripting to generate a XML file and then using XSLT to transform it and display on the website.
2. Transform large content from ERP systems like PeopleSoft, Banner etc. where information about students, faculties, courses etc. are all available as XMLs. This information can then be transformed to web pages, PDFs etc.
3. Live score tickers on athletics website and mobile apps- Where you have a web service from the system that is used for keeping the stats/scores at the stadium and that web service/XML is then transformed and used on the Website, mobile app etc.

There are many more use cases involving transformation of large XML files and streaming can result in processing/transforming such large files much more efficiently.